# How do I want to write a function that will run based on the first letter of a line?

Tags: r, function, readline

#R
I've been trying to come up with an idea logic please help me.

```
if first character of line = "H" run function Header{
  if first character of line = "P" run function Patient{
.....other
  }
}
```

function in line

```
  If "H" is first character of line = 
   Header <- string::str_split(Hline,fixed('|')) # Hline = String to set to collect H line. 
 ID_H <- Header[1] # [1] = The first value is extracted from the line by '|'.
 Del_H <- Header[2]
```

There are five types of out-of-the-box functions based on the first letter of the line read.
If you have an example that would be great.
please help me
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a wrapper around `readline()`, where you extract the first character of the input and use `switch()` to pull in the relevant function. Note that you can't use `'str'[1]` to get `'s'` in R, that will just be vector indexing that returns `'str'`. We can use `substr()`.

```r
reader <- function() {
  x <- readline()
  x1 <- tolower(substr(x, 1, 1))
  switch(
    x1,
    h = cumsum(1:4),
    p = cumprod(1:4)
  )
}

reader()
#> hardy
#> [1]  1  3  6 10

reader()
#> plenty
#> [1]  1  2  6 24
```